# Best compression method for sequence of uint64s when order preservation doesn't matter

Tags: hash, compression

I am storing arrays of 10,000 uint64s. The values are hashes so are pretty evenly distributed across the full 64-bit space, making them not great for compression (zip only manages around 3% saving).

However, the order of the values is not important. Can I use this extra piece of knowledge to craft a more effective compression routine? An immediate thought was to sort them in order and then bucketize them, eg "next x values all have prefix a1b2c3" or something. This can certainly improve on zip, but can I do better? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theoretical best benefit you can get is log2(10000!) bits, which is about 15K bytes out of your initial 80K bytes. Less than a 20% reduction.

If you really want to try to squeeze most of that out, you can try to compress the differences between successive hashes in sorted order. The first hash would be sent as is, followed by 9,999 differences. I would separate the high 12 bits of each 64-bit difference off into a different block, and compress that with a standard lossless compressor. The low 52 bits of each hash difference will essentially be noise, and so send that as is without trying to compress it.

You can play with the number 12 to see what gives you the best compression. Maybe 11 or 13 will work better.

Comment: Tried it, just for fun. Turns out my first guess of 12 was correct. That gives a compression ratio of 0.8260. Surprisingly close to the theoretical best compression of 0.8149.